# How to make two center sliders in Swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

The page has a Swiper slider. The swiper-slide contains an image width: 660px and height: 600px. Their location: two slides in the center and on the sides of the halves of the slides.
How can I put them in such an arrangement and size so that the pictures are not compressed. Below is the layout diagram and code.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".main-slider", {
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
});
```

```css
.main-slider .swiper-slide img {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-slider .swiper-slide {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 673px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container swiper main-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="./img/slider-1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-2.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-3.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-4.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired layout by adding horizontal padding to swiper. Here is what you can do:

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".main-slider", {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  centeredSlides: false,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  initialSlide: 2,
});
```

```css
.main-slider .swiper-slide img {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper {
   padding: 0 15% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container swiper main-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-1.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-2.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-3.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-4.png" alt=""></div>    
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="./img/slider-5.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my solution I've added `.swiper { padding: 0 15% !important; }` so slides on sides will be partially visible.

In Swiper initialization:

1. `slidesPerView: 2` so 2 slides will be in view.
2. `initialSlide: 2` the loop fix, so first partial slide will be visible.
3. `centeredSlides: false` we don't need to center one slide.

P.S. Keep in mind that if you want loop to work, because of nature of how the loop mode works (it will rearrange slides), total number of slides must be >= slidesPerView * 2. And for our case we need extra one slide.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by CSS

```
.slider-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.slider-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add slidesPerView: 2

const swiper = new Swiper(".main-slider", {
loop: true,
centeredSlides: true,
spaceBetween: 30,
slidesPerView: 2,
});